# Yii2 - Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to join two tables in a query :

```html
- sc_cours -
    idCour
    volHoraireCour
    idMat

- sc_matieres -
    idMat
    nomMat
```

the code of the query is the following

```html
$query->select('*')
      ->from('sc_cours')
      ->innerJoin('sc_matieres', 'sc_cours.idMat = sc_matieres.idMat');
```

But i get this following error

```html
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Table/alias: 'sc_matieres' non unique
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `sc_cours` INNER JOIN `sc_matieres` ON sc_cours.idMat = sc_matieres.idMat INNER JOIN `sc_matieres` ON sc_cours.idMat = sc_matieres.idMat
```

Do you know what's the main problem guys? Thanks you!

Comment: Try this -


$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query->select(['a.*','b.*'])
->from(['a' => 'sc_cours'])
->innerJoin(['b' => 'sc_matieres'],'a.idMat = b.idMat')
->all();

Comment: I have the same error, but this time on the aliases                                                             Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Table/alias: 'b' non unique
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `sc_cours` `a` INNER JOIN `sc_matieres` `b` ON a.idMat = b.idMat INNER JOIN `sc_matieres` `b` ON a.idMat = b.idMat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with `->ScCours::find()->join('mat')` I've this error `Missing argument 2 for yii\db\Query::join()` , But Thank you, you put me on the right path because it works when i try with `with` , so i've just done `->ScCours::find()->with('mat')`. That's worked now, thank you again  Borisa Eric for your precious help !

Answer (score 0):

From error you can see that you have two inner joins exact same. Define relation in model and than just do `->innerJoin('nameOfRelation');`

Comment: There's already the relation in the model                                                           
public function getMat()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ScMatieres::className(), ['idMat' => 'idMat']);
    }                                                                                                                                  but if i do ->innerJoin('classe) , it wil take the nameofRelation as a table ...                 Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 's'coolapp.classe' n'existe pas
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `sc_cours` `a` INNER JOIN `classe`

Comment: why `classe` if your relation name is `getMat()` then your relation should be `mat` and it would take from tabel defined in `ScMatieres`

Comment: sorry it's me who do an error here (it just because i do the same with another tables `sc_classes` , sorry for that again ...) but unfortunately even if i write `mat `, i get the same error, telling me that `the table mat does not exist`

Comment: No need for saying sorry, we are here to help each other. It should not get table name from relation, instead it should take table name from ScMatieres. Can you provide all code related to this issue.